# how to redraw modified image using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

let me explain you what I do. I need to draw bigg image near to 5000px to 2688px. So I can't draw whole image because in browser it's too long. I decided to add scroll bar to see whole image. The following script allows me to draw a part of canvas

```
var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function(){
          canvasW = 5376
          canvasH = 2688
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, canvasW, canvasH);
     };
img.src = "image.png";
```

Now imagine I want to apply effects like blur or brigthness, contrast etc, My canvas will change, so how can I redraw modified canvas (with effect and not the first one.

I tried to check on stackoverflow but the examples is to redraw image from the first one. I mean the drawing is not from a modifed canvas.

I tried to store base64 of my canvas and redraw by using base64 :

```
var image = new Image()

    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.drawImage(image, canMouseX, canMouseY, canvasW, canvasH);

})

image.src = bases64[bases64.length - 1]
```

It doesn't work because by storing base64 there is just a part of canvas that is redraw. If you want more details clone my repo on : https://github.com/wyllisMonteiro/draggingScroll/tree/master

I want to find a solution to redraw a modified canvas

Comment: You're talking about css effects, such as `blur(10px)` or `brightness(0.1)`?

Comment: No, I'm using blur with canvas like stackblur library and not CSS

Comment: When you are drawing the image you are drawing it from the mouse position (`canMouseX, canMouseY`). That's why there is just a part of canvas that is redrawn. Try replacing `canMouseX, canMouseY` with `0,0`

Comment: It was the goal I want to draw a part of my canvas but how to redraw a part of canvas that is modified by bluring ? Do you understand my problem ?

Comment: Look at my second part of code, I want to use image blured instead of basic image, So I load another image as the second part of code but src is base64 that contains just a part of my image instead of whole image